# Laravel Deployment - Module not found: Can't resolve 'Quill'

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm having issues deploying my laravel project onto my Digital Ocean server using Laravel Forge. `npm run prod` and `npm run watch` work perfect on localhost but when I deploy the project live I get errors compiling the JS.

/node_modues/quill/ is definitely installed on the server too.

**Here is the error:**

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/user.js 3:15-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Quill' in '/home/forge/sieved.co/resources/js'
```

**My user.js file:**

```
require('./quill.js');

window.Quill = require('Quill');

var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

**My quill.js file also in the resources folder:**

```
import Quill from 'quill/core';

import Toolbar from 'quill/modules/toolbar';
import Snow from 'quill/themes/snow';

import Bold from 'quill/formats/bold';
import Italic from 'quill/formats/italic';
import Header from 'quill/formats/header';


Quill.register({
  'modules/toolbar': Toolbar,
  'themes/snow': Snow,
  'formats/bold': Bold,
  'formats/italic': Italic,
  'formats/header': Header
});

export default Quill;
```

I don't get these errors locally so I'm confused what could be causing it to happen on the server. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a JS dependency, the package Quill.

You can either install it using `npm` by running `npm install quill` or pulling it from a CDN. See [Quills homepage](https://quilljs.com/docs/download/) for details.

Then you can include it by using `window.Quill = require('quill');` Please see the lowercase writing `quill` instead of your `Quill` inside the `require`.

Comment: Thanks, it was the Uppercase Q that caused the issue.

Comment: This doesn't answer @user3479267 question as to why in local development the uppercase `Quill` works while on the server it has to be lowercase but it does solve the issue by not using titlecase.